# Check value and run calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to calculate the tax of the products. I am using the following script for it:

```
<script>
    function getTotalTax() {                      
        var numVal1 = Number(document.getElementById("price1").value);
        var numVal6 = Number(document.getElementById("tax1").value);
        var numVal2 = Number(document.getElementById("price2").value);
        var numVal7 = Number(document.getElementById("tax2").value);

        var totalValue2 = (numVal1 / '100' * numVal6) + (numVal2 / '100' * numVal7);
        document.getElementById("total_tax").value = totalValue2.toFixed(2);
    }
</script>
```

Now I want to extend this script. I added three more textboxes. In the first textbox I want to add only the calculation for where the tax='10', in the second I want to add only where the tax='20' and in the third I want to add only where the tax='25'.

I need to make a script like this:

```
var totalValue3 = IF numval='10'(numVal1 / '100' * numVal6) + IF numval='10'(numVal2 / '100' * numVal7)
var totalValue3 = IF numval='20'(numVal1 / '100' * numVal6) + IF numval='20'(numVal2 / '100' * numVal7)
var totalValue3 = IF numval='25'(numVal1 / '100' * numVal6) + IF numval='25'(numVal2 / '100' * numVal7)
```

But this script is not working.

Does someone know how I can make a calculation for this?

**JSfiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/mm2fLne9/

**Update:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the code you are looking for.
https://jsfiddle.net/mm2fLne9/8/

```
function getTotalTax() {                      
        var numVal1 = Number(document.getElementById("price1").value);
        var numVal6 = Number(document.getElementById("tax1").value);
        var numVal2 = Number(document.getElementById("price2").value);
        var numVal7 = Number(document.getElementById("tax2").value);

        var totalValue2 = (numVal1 / '100' * numVal6) + (numVal2 / '100' * numVal7);
        document.getElementById("total_tax").value = totalValue2.toFixed(2);

        var totalValue3 = (numVal6 ==10 ?(numVal1 / 100 * numVal6) :0) + (numVal7 ==10 ?(numVal2 / 100 * numVal7):0);
        document.getElementById("ttax1").value = totalValue3.toFixed(2);

        var totalValue4 = (numVal6 ==20 ?(numVal1 / 100 * numVal6) :0) + (numVal7 ==20 ?(numVal2 / 100 * numVal7):0);
        document.getElementById("ttax2").value = totalValue4.toFixed(2);            
   }
```

Comment: The script works for a part but there are still some issues. If I enter `10` in in the first textbox `tax1` the script calculates the tax and sends the data to the textbox for value `10`. When I enter `20` it sends also the data to the textbox for value `10`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/mm2fLne9/2/

Comment: You have 2 tax fields, which tax field you are referring? What is the actual functionality?

Comment: If I enter `10` in `tax1`. The data will send to `ttax1`. After that when I enter `20` in `tax2` the script sends the data also to `ttax1`. The data for the second needs to be send to `ttax2`

Comment: So ttax1 will be populated when you enter 10 or 20 in tax1? when this ttax3 comes?

Comment: No. When I enter `10` in `tax1`, `Ttax1` gets populated. When I enter `20` in `tax2` after I entered `10` in `tax1`, `Ttax1` gets polulated again. This is wrong. `tax2` needs to populate `Ttax2` because the value is `20`

Comment: See update in my first post. `tax2` populates the wrong textbox

Comment: Now `Ttax2` gets populated, but with wrong data. When I enter `10` in `tax1` and `20` in `tax2`. `ttax1` should be `10` and `ttax2` should be `20`. Now I get `30` in both.

Comment: Because your calculation is same for all the 3 fields

Comment: I dont get It. the calculation is the same, but the script needs to seperate the data. If value = `10` it needs to populate ttax1, if its `20` it needs to populate ttax2. I updated the script a bit, but its still populating the wrong textbox https://jsfiddle.net/mm2fLne9/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148751/discussion-between-vineesh-and-john).